# iOS 11: Update User Location Coordinates In Background on Interval

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios11, swift4

I have recently picked up Swift again and I'm working on an app that requires me to get the user coordinates on an interval for the most accurate pull. My app is authorized to always track the user location. My issue is figuring out how exactly I get the coordinates updates to fire and as well as accepting that into my app running in the background.

I have explored in the AppDelegate file under the background function but I was able to get execute the update location via [This Script](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61847) although it resulting in a very fast pull and the timer adjustments didn't seem to work. It kept the energy impact:**High** so I would like to find aless impact logic. Hoping some one will be able to assist.

Please see .Swift source below.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//
//
//  Created by Truman  on 10/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 . All rights reserved.
//



import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



    @IBOutlet var date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lastLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var currentLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imageConnectionStatus: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var lastLocationMap: MKMapView!



    //Get Current Date - Tru
    private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }()




    //Location Declaration
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
                                                                  regionRadius, regionRadius)
        lastLocationMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Start View Did Load


        //Setup location manager
        // If location services is enabled get the users location
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.activityType = .otherNavigation
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            // Print out the location to the console
        }



        self.date.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedDate")
        self.lastLocation.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedLocation")



        var setLocation : String
        var dataLastLocation : String

        //Save device location.
        //saveLocation()



        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 33.4641856959831, longitude: -111.919245965591)
        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation )
        //End View Did Load
    }


    var activelocation : String = ""

    //Did update locations Method
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

        let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
        let currentLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        let currentLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude

        if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            currentLocation.text = "\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)"

            //print("longitude = \(location.coordinate.longitude), latitude = \(location.coordinate.latitude)")


            // Need to use Current User Location vs Last Seen location in Maps URLS Below
            activelocation =  "http://maps.google.com/?saddr=\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedLocation")!)&daddr=\(currentLatitude),\(currentLongitude)"


            self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true



        }

    }

    //Setting Saved data values--
    func setPersistent(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard



        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

            let oldDate = self.date.text
            defaults.set(oldDate, forKey: "savedDate")
            self.date.text = oldDate
            print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedDate"))

            //locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            let oldLocation = self.currentLocation.text
            defaults.set(oldLocation, forKey: "savedLocation")
            self.lastLocation.text = "Saved Location:\(oldLocation)"
            // print("this is the old location:\(oldLocation)")
            print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedLocation"))



            let saveDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "saveLast")
            let saveLastLocation = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "saveLastLocation")


        }



    }


    func saveLocation(){


        // print("longitude = \(location.coordinate.longitude), latitude = \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
    }

    //Did Fail Update
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error){
        print(Error.self)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



                //Get Current Date and time.
                func getTodayString() -> String{

                    let date = Date()
                    let calender = Calendar.current
                    let components = calender.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,], from: date)

                    let today_string = String(month)

                    return today_string

                }

                let today : String


                today = getTodayString()
                UserDefaults.standard.set("\(today)", forKey: "saveLast")

                //self.lastLocation.text = "hello"

                self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                self.setPersistent()

            } else if state == false {


                let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {


                }

            }





        //    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let now = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss"
        let month = dateFormatter.string(from: now as Date)
        //self.date.text = dateFormatter.string(from: now as Date)



        //Get Current Date andd time.
        func getTodayString() -> String{

            let date = Date()
            let calender = Calendar.current
            let components = calender.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,], from: date)

            let today_string = String(month)

            return today_string

        }

        let today : String

        today = getTodayString()
        UserDefaults.standard.set("\(today)", forKey: "saveLast")



    }


}
```